Grisly war movie following two soldiers after the main conflict on patrol
I'm looking to identify what I remember was a fairly grisly war movie, at least 10-15 years old. Perhaps it was a WW2 flick but it certainly was not a modern conflict. There are four scenes I remember specifically but I think in general plot was about two soldiers on guard duty/patrol after a conflict. 
Scenes 1 / 2 (related):
Two soldiers (speaking English) are walking through the bombed out ruins of a town. They walk into a house and find an old woman there. The woman is talking in a different language but she is friendly. She offers the two soldiers an apple. One of the soldiers seemingly accepts the apple then a few moments later suddenly brings out his combat knife and chops of some of her fingers. They then leave the woman there writhing in pain, bleeding and walk out. 
Later in the movie other soldiers run past the same building and she is laying there dead on her bed.
Scenes 3 / 4 (related):
Two soldiers (I cannot remember it is the same two as above) are guarding a bridge, one is in a machine gun nest close to the bridge and the other is a sniper further away. They are under orders to shoot anyone who approaches it. The sniper spots a young girl walking towards the bridge with a small farm animal. They have had incidents of children being used as saboteurs in this conflict, after some hesitation the sniper shoots the girl and she falls into the river. 
Later on the soldiers are idly talking over the radio when another child approaches the bridge, a young boy. The sniper is getting ready to shoot him when the machine-gunner tells him to hold his fire since he is having issues with the prospect of another child being shot. The machine-gunner beckons the boy to come over. When the boy gets close he throws a grenade into the machine gun nest, killing the soldier. I cannot remember if the boy got away.

The movie is Savior. 1998 war film.
Matching scenes from the plot:

The film moves forward to the war in Bosnia where "Guy" and Peter are now fighting for the Bosnian Serbs, stationed on a bridge separating them and the Bosnian Muslims in a town. Guy mans a sniper post overlooking the bridge, and witnesses Peter's death when Peter drops his guard at a checkpoint and a young girl throws a grenade at him. Guy in turn shoots a boy crossing the bridge in pursuit of his goat.
Guy is then seen searching the Muslim side of the town following a ceasefire along with a Bosnian Serb soldier Goran (Sergej Trifunović). In one house they find an elderly Muslim woman who is confined to bed and shell-shocked and a dead woman. Guy also finds a sleeping baby who has been hidden in a wardrobe but does not inform Goran who hacks a finger off the old woman in order to steal her ring.
[Wikipedia]

